# How to detect a GET request on another file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to make a login system, and in the login page I want to check for a GET request 'from' (e.g. *http://localhost/login_system/login.php?**from**=http://localhost/login_system/profile.php*). The idea is that the backend will redirect the user to the value of the from GET request after they have logged in. The problem is that I'm doing this through ajax, so the login.php file is linked to the backend php file through a JS file. So when I check for the GET request from the backend file, I'm actually checking for the GET request on the current file, not on the login file. Is there a way to check for a GET request on the login page from the backend file?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is there anything not working with the approach you've suggested?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to write it in Ajax but you can add extra information on your request headers so you know where you're coming from.